# How can I set a variable header of a TableView (not of a section) programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I set a variable header of a TableView (not of a section) programmatically, without having to worry about the placement?

```
    let headerView = UILabel()
    headerView.text = x
    headerView.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 44)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

I got this code, but I don't think I can place the header exactly like it is a 'real' header. Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Create an UIView and place your UILabel inside it as a subview.

Comment: What is your actual question? What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dmitriy said, this is a normal way to do it:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Position is however defined by the frame you set in it, so if position is what you want different, you have to play with this line of your code:

```
headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 44)
```

E.g., if you want the label to be centered, you can for example do it this way:

```
headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 44)
headerView.textAlignment = .centered
```

This would span the label across the width of the tableView and the text alignment would place it to center. Of course, for this to work, the tableView frame has to be already calculated at this point (so maybe you would had to put the line with frame calculation in the `layoutSubviews` method).

Answer (score 0):

I think this `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView` - it's normal way to make header in UITableView.

Comment: If I use this code, the header is in the left corner, which I don't want it to be

Comment: Then you must send a correct argument there: headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 44)